# SlidingWindows Python Apache Beam duplicate the data

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**The problem**

Each time the system receive a message from pubsub with a Sliding Windows it been duplicated

---

**The code**

```
 | 'Parse dictionary' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem['Serial'], int(elem['Value'])))    
 | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.SlidingWindows(30, 15),accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
 | 'Count' >> beam.CombinePerKey(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn())
```

---

**The output**

If I only send one message from pub/sub and try to print what I have after the sliding window finish with the code:

```
class print_row2(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, row=beam.DoFn.ElementParam, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
        print row, timestamp2str(float(window.start)), timestamp2str(float(window.end)),timestamp2str(float(timestamp))
```

**The result**

```
('77777', 120.0) 2018-11-16 08:21:15.000 2018-11-16 08:21:45.000 2018-11-16 08:21:45.000
('77777', 120.0) 2018-11-16 08:21:30.000 2018-11-16 08:22:00.000 2018-11-16 08:22:00.000
```

If I print the message before `'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.SlidingWindows(30, 15))` I only get once

---

**The process** in "graphic mode:

```
  time: ----t+00---t+15---t+30----t+45----t+60------>
             :      :      :       :       :
  w1:        |=X===========|       :       :
  w2:               |==============|       :
  ...
```

The message X was sent only once at the begining of the slidingwindow, it should only be received once, but is been receiving twice

I have tried with both AccumulationMode values, also with a trigger=AftyerWatermark but i can not fix the problem.

**What could be wrong?**

---

**Extra**

With FixedWindows this is the correct code for my porpouse:

```
| 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1 * 30))
| 'Speed Average' >> beam.GroupByKey()
| "Calculating average" >> beam.CombineValues(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn())
```

or

```
| 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1 * 30))
| "Calculating average" >> beam.CombinePerKey(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn())
```

Answer (score 0):

All elements that belong to the window are emitted. If an element belongs to multiple windows it will be emitted in each window.

Accumulation mode only matters if you plan to handle late data/multiple trigger firings. In this case discarding mode gives you only new elements in the window  when the trigger fires again, i.e. emits only the elements that arrived in the same window since previous trigger firing, the elements that were already emitted are not emitted again and are discarded. In accumulating mode the whole window will be emitted for every trigger firing, it will include old elements that were already emitted last time and new elements that have arrived since then.

If I understand your example you have sliding windows, they have a length of 30 seconds, and they start every 15 seconds. So they overlap for 15 seconds:

```
  time: ----t+00---t+15---t+30----t+45----t+60------>
             :      :      :       :       :
  w1:        |=============|       :       :
  w2:               |==============|       :
  w3:                      |===============|
  ...
```

So any element in your case will belong to at least two windows (except for first and last windows).

E.g. in your example, if your message was sent between 17:07:15 and 17:07:30 it will appear in both windows.

Fixed windows don't overlap so element can belong only to one window:

```
  time: ----t+00---t+15---t+30----t+45----t+60------>
             :             :               :
  w1:        |=============|               :
  w2:                      |===============|
  w3:                                      |====...
  ...
```

More about windows here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have used your graphic to explain what I did. So the problem is that the message was receiving at the beggining of the slide (I have make this test several times with the same result) and I can not understand why I receive twice

Comment: The physical time when you send the message can be different from what Beam considers the event timestamp. Can you extract the timestamp from the element and check what Beam thinks the timestamp of the element is? (I think you can do access it in ParDo with DoFn.TimestampParam: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a2b0ad14f1525d1a645cb26f5b8ec45692d9d54e/sdks/python/apache_beam/testing/test_stream_test.py#L108)

Comment: Also it may depend on how you configure the IO source

Comment: Added in the main post. It's like Beam considers twice the first message and both at the final of the windowsliding.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, however in java. I have a window with 10 seconds duration and a step of 3 seconds. When an event is emitted from the mqtt topic, that I subscribe to, it looks like the ParDo function that I have runs and emits the first and only event to all of the three "constructed" windows.

X is the event that i send at a random timestamp:  2020-09-15T21:17:57.292Z

```
  time: ----t+00---t+15---t+30----t+45----t+60------>
             :      :      :       :       :
  w1:        |X============|       :       :
  w2:               |X=============|       :
  w3:                      |X==============|
  ...
```

Even the same timestamp is assigned to them!! I must really doing something completely wrong.

I use Scala 2.12 and BEAM 2.23 with a Direct Runner.

***[Hint]:*** I use states in the processElement function! Where the state is being hold per key + window. Maybe there is a bug there? I will try to test it without states.

**UPDATE:** Removed the state fields and the single event is assigned to one window.