# Remove duplicate events from unbounded stream using sliding window approach in Apache Beam

Tags: python, duplicates, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stream-processing

I am trying to remove duplicate events from an unbounded stream of data. I tried using sliding windows (60 seconds window with 30 seconds period) along with grouping events by unique key but it seems to be not working since the events that belong to multiple windows are emitted multiple times ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304174/slidingwindows-python-apache-beam-duplicate-the-data)).

I have the following code:

```
(
    elements
    | "Convert To Tuple" >> Map(lambda element: (element.id, element))
    | "Window" >> WindowInto(SlidingWindows(60, 30), trigger=AfterCount(1), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
    | "Group" >> GroupByKey()
    | "Process" >> ParDo(MyCustomFn())
```

I know I could use `FixedWindows` to achieve my goal. However, it's possible to miss some of the duplicate events with `FixedWindows`. Therefore, I was trying to figure out how to use `SlidingWindows` (maybe using an additional group by operations or something like that).

**I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to deduplicate events using `SlidingWindows`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SlidingWindows isn't really a good way to do deduplication for exactly the reason you've found: the spec for SlidingWindows is that you get one output per window the element is in.

In Java, you can use the [Deduplicate](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.21.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Deduplicate.html) transform to do this.  It lets you configure how far to look back in time (either processing time or event time) to look for duplicate values.  In Python, this doesn't exist yet, although you could write your own transform based on Java's version to do the same thing.

Comment: I was thinking of applying a global window and group by operators after sliding window. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: That will lead to indefinitely growing state, since you'll be keeping all keys around forever to remember which elements you've seen.  The method in Deduplicate with a stateful DoFn that explicitly GCs the dedup state after a timeout is the best method.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try using similar function in python. Thank you for the advice

Comment: I believe it already exists based on [this doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.transforms.deduplicate.html?highlight=deduplicate)